# Sealing baseboards in an old home

Tags: insulation, energy-efficiency

I own a beautiful old Victorian home from 1905. A few months ago, we got a home energy audit. Unsurprisingly, the audit revealed that our walls leak like a sieve. The auditor said we had literally the worst blower door result she had ever seen. One of the suggestions was trying to do something to seal the gaps between our baseboards, as this was a large source of draftiness (anecdotally, this agrees with my experience - floors near the outside walls in the winter tend to be very cold and have drafts, and the baseboards have some pretty large gaps - as big as 1/4").

My question is how I would go about sealing these. Some baseboards are painted white, but most of the baseboards are beautifully stained and original to the house, with quarter-round at floor level (although with some substantial gaps). We have hardwood floors throughout the house which are also original. I read some advice that suggested pulling off quarter-round and shoving backer rod in there and reattaching the quarter-round, but I'm not super-comfortable doing that since I'm worried I'd destroy the trim in the process and it would be hard/impossible to replace. Is applying a clear, flexible caulk all the way around between the quarter-round and the floors feasible? If so, is there anything I should know about application? I've done a small amount of caulking before, but not a ton.
[image: example baseboard gaps]

[image: example baseboard gaps]

[image: example baseboard gaps]

[image: example baseboard gaps]

Comment: Caulking will help a bit.  Leaking like that would probably mean the insulation is not good in the walls.  Having an inspection camera(only needs small holes) will let you see what is in the walls(1905 might be newspaper or brick).  Can have insulation blown inside the walls, also small holes, from inside or outside.

Comment: I would be very fussy about choosing the correct caulk if you go that way. My instinct is that clear ALEX would quickly stain. My instinct is that I would want an unpaintable caulk like silicone. I would either tape both edges of the joints or recaulk my tub first and finally practice with a finishing tool and soapy water or denatured alcohol.

Comment: A photo would help

Comment: Added some photos.